# Switch statement on char variable

Tags: c++

A library we are using defines constants and we have:

```
const char field[] = "666"
```

and I would like to:

```
switch(an_int){
    case field:
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I get a compiler error saying field is not usable in a constant expression (GCC 5.2).

I would really wish to avoid modifying the declaration of field if possible.

Comment: You really should consult the documentation first: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: @NathanOliver this bit: "a single non-array variable"?

Comment: Yes that and the whole *condition* and *constant_expression* parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`field` is an array. It is not a single value you can `switch` on.

You're trying to `switch` on the contents of a character array, when it is interpreted as an integer value.

Use `atoi()`, or a helper `std::istringstream`'s `operator >>`, to convert the array into an `int` variable, then `switch` on it.

Comment: You cannot use the converted `int` from `atoi` or friends in a switch case either, because it won't be a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible to have switch statement on char array/string. In case you are sure that the field will contain numeric value then convert char array to integer.

Comment: You cannot "cast" a char array, like this, to an integer. This statement makes no sense. The term "casting" has a specific meaning in C++, and this ain't it.

Comment: @Sam, I meant it to convert and not cast. Thanks for catching it and I have updated my comment.

Comment: How do you propose to convert the string to an integer at compile time? The case must be a constant expression.

Comment: it can be atoi() as suggested by @Sam

Comment: As I commented on Sams answer, `atoi` cannot be used. Function calls are not constant expressions (unless the function is declared `constexpr`, which `atoi` is not).